# OpenCV KNN draw matches

Tags: opencv, type-conversion, match, draw, knn

I'm using KNN to classify images. Now my problem is how to draw the results.

[Click here to get the documentation for KNN in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html)

I'm using the function find_nearest, which constructor looks like this:
`C++: float CvKNearest::find_nearest(const Mat& samples, int k, Mat& results, Mat& neighborResponses, Mat& dists)`

Where the parameters are:

samples : Input samples stored by rows. It is a single-precision floating-point matrix of `number\_of\_samples \times number\_of\_features size`.

k : Number of used nearest neighbors. It must satisfy constraint: `k \le CvKNearest::get_max_k().`

results : Vector with results of prediction (regression or classification) for each input sample. It is a `single-precision floating-point` vector with `number_of_samples` elements.

neighbors : Optional output pointers to the neighbor vectors themselves. It is an array of `k*samples->rows` pointers.

neighborResponses : Optional output values for corresponding neighbors. It is a single-precision floating-point matrix of `number\_of\_samples \times k size`.

dist : Optional output distances from the input vectors to the corresponding neighbors. It is a single-precision floating-point matrix of `number\_of\_samples \times k size`.

A posible implementation would look like this:

```
#include "ml.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    const int K = 10;
    int i, j, k, accuracy;
    float response;
    int train_sample_count = 100;
    CvRNG rng_state = cvRNG(-1);
    CvMat* trainData = cvCreateMat( train_sample_count, 2, CV_32FC1 );
    CvMat* trainClasses = cvCreateMat( train_sample_count, 1, CV_32FC1 );
    IplImage* img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 500, 500 ), 8, 3 );
    float _sample[2];
    CvMat sample = cvMat( 1, 2, CV_32FC1, _sample );
    cvZero( img );

    CvMat trainData1, trainData2, trainClasses1, trainClasses2;

    // form the training samples
    cvGetRows( trainData, &trainData1, 0, train_sample_count/2 );
    cvRandArr( &rng_state, &trainData1, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(200,200), cvScalar(50,50) );

    cvGetRows( trainData, &trainData2, train_sample_count/2, train_sample_count );
    cvRandArr( &rng_state, &trainData2, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(300,300), cvScalar(50,50) );

    cvGetRows( trainClasses, &trainClasses1, 0, train_sample_count/2 );
    cvSet( &trainClasses1, cvScalar(1) );

    cvGetRows( trainClasses, &trainClasses2, train_sample_count/2, train_sample_count );
    cvSet( &trainClasses2, cvScalar(2) );

    // learn classifier
    CvKNearest knn( trainData, trainClasses, 0, false, K );
    CvMat* nearests = cvCreateMat( 1, K, CV_32FC1);

    for( i = 0; i < img->height; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < img->width; j++ )
        {
            sample.data.fl[0] = (float)j;
            sample.data.fl[1] = (float)i;

            // estimate the response and get the neighbors' labels
            response = knn.find_nearest(&sample,K,0,0,nearests,0);

            // compute the number of neighbors representing the majority
            for( k = 0, accuracy = 0; k < K; k++ )
            {
                if( nearests->data.fl[k] == response)
                    accuracy++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now back to the problem. I want to use the function DrawMatches. [Click here to see the description](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html). This function expects its input as DMatch-Type matrix. So as you see Knn.find_nearest does not give me any return of this type. Do you have any suggestion how to convert those?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using knn classifier (in machine learning module), not descriptor matching using knn (in features2d) module. You can use `drawMatches` only in the latter case.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how to change it?Or maybe an example?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?#descriptormatcher-knnmatch) fro knn match, and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html) for a full example with features

Comment: Why can't i use the descriptors of a picture to train the classifier and later on to use the classifier to classify pictures. I think the descriptor matching does the same